# Display a random post only once until all posts have been shown/

Tags: wordpress, post, types, while-loop

I want get the ID of a random post with post type "Advertisement" and add it to an array. This array needs to keep track of all the ID's of posts it iterates through.

I need to get a random "Advertisement", get its ID and add it to an array. However the array is overwritten on each loop and I do not understand why.

```
    $allPosts = array();
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Advertisement',
                   'posts_per_page' => 1,
                   'orderby' => 'rand');

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        array_push($allPosts, get_the_ID());
    endwhile;

    foreach($allPosts as $p) {
        echo($p);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get different posts when reloading the page, you need to save the list of those already shown in the database. For example, it can be implemented like this:

```
$post_type = 'Advertisement';
$option_name = 'advertisement_list';

$getAllPosts = get_option($option_name);
$allPosts = empty($getAllPosts) ? [] : $getAllPosts;

$args = [
    'post__not_in' => $allPosts,
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
];
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if($loop->have_posts()) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        array_push( $allPosts, get_the_ID() );
        echo get_the_ID();
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();

$total_posts = wp_count_posts($post_type)->publish;
if(count($allPosts) == $total_posts){
    delete_option($option_name);
} else {
    update_option($option_name, $allPosts);
}
```